# Can I change the text content in a <span> based on the width of the <span>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As the width of my screen decreases for a smaller mobile device I would like to be able to change the sentence I have in my  to a shorter sentence so it will fit on one line.

Essentially I would like to have the text when the:
-width is > 350px say "this is my text in the span"
-width is < 350px saw "this is span text"

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: You can check width of `window` (or `span` or whatever) and decide which text to put into a `span`.

Comment: You can use media queries and show/hide different spans depending on the width

Comment: If text is static you can use css media query and css content for text.

Comment: What about `text-overflow: ellipsis`?

Comment: why not use media queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

or via CSS:

```css
.over350 {
    display: inline;
}
.below350 {
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    .over350 {
        display: none;
    }
    .below350 {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

```html
<span class="over350">this is my text in the span</span>
<span class="below350">this is span text</span>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this by hooking to the `resize` event of the window, and inspecting the width of your `span` there. Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.mySpan').text(function() {
        return $(this).width() >= 350 ? 'this is my text in the span' : 'this is span text';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Gotcha! 
Take a span alone and leave the text-content empty like this

```html
<span class="magic_span"></span>
```

and now in css

```css
.magic_span::after{
    content: "this is span text";
}

@media screen and (min-width : 350px){
    .magic_span::after{
        content: "this is my text in the span";
    }
}
```